# New hard drive access

Tags: upgrade

I'm a Ubuntu newbie.

My question is: I have Ubuntu 13.10  (64 bits) installed on a Dell desktop with 2 GB of memory. It shares a HDD with Windows 7. I recently installed an additional 1 TB drive.

I have been trying for days to make the second hard drive readable from another Windows XP machine over my network without success. The second drive is formatted to ext3.. I figured I would try to expand the home directory which is readable from the XP machine.

My goal is to use Ubuntu as a movie and music server. Also, I am trying to move away from Microsoft as I have already installed programs that do the same thing I can do on my XP machine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows cannot read the Linux filesystems without third party drivers.

You have several options,

1. use FAT32 --does not support Linux permissions so you will have issues with files that need to maintain ownership.
2. use NTFS --also does not support Linux permissions, also susceptible to corruption(Linux will have issues with a corrupted NTFS)
3. use EXT file systems and install third party drivers in Windows

The program you need to install in Windows is [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

for more detailed info on Ex2Read see the sourgeforce page(in the link above), or the page I used as my source for this answer: [How to read Ext3/Ext4 linux partition from windows 7](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html)(this page also tells you how to install and use Ext2read as well as screenshots).

If you wish to also use Windows to write to the Ext file system then you would need to install [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), this is also mentioned on my source page.

Personally, if I only needed to access the EXT files(read only) I would avoid Ext2Fsd ; I don't have any reason to doubt the program, I would be afraid that Windows would clumsily botch the files(I have no hard facts for this opinion, but as Microsoft has no love for Linux, they have no reason to prevent regressions in their updates that would injure a Linux FS).

---

Disclaimer:   I no longer use Windows so I cannot test this information, but [ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/) is a good website and I would use this info and the program myself if I needed it.